# How to dynamic create table?

Tags: sql, c, sqlite

The table field I need is dynamic, sometimes I need 3x3 = 9 fields, sometimes I need 5x5 = 25 fields, it is possible to go further to 15x15, depends on the configuration.

The creating table code I am using is:

```
const char* sqlCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE Q_TABLE 
       (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, action0 int, action1 int, ..... action225 );";
```

I need a way to create this table dynamically.

--- Update ---

I am using sqlite3

The table is a q-learning q table, which has two inputs and returns a q value, 
ex:

[When using this table in C coding]

```
#define STATES 100 // This value is dynamic change in each build.
#define ACTIONS 10 // This value is also dynamic change in each build.
int Q_Table[STATES][ACTIONS]={};
```

What's the better way to create this table?

Comment: Do you using mssql?

Comment: A series of columns with the same name as prefix and numbers as suffix often indicate that one rather wants a table with one column for all values and a different **row** for each value.

Comment: Just write a `script` of shell or python or other else to complete this requirement.